# String Search in two different Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe, search, string-concatenation

I have a list of strings in a dataframe `df1`

```
temp=df1.loc[df1['quartier']=='quartier1', 'Titre']
```

The output is:

```
108      T/42322/C/
108      T/37666/C/
108      T/31411/C/
108    T/118487/01/
108    T/118489/01/
           ...     
108    T/108034/01/
108    T/108045/01/
108    T/108047/01/
108    T/108032/01/
108    T/108045/01/

Shortlist=','.join(temp)

T/42322/C/,T/37666/C/,T/31411/C/,....
```

and I would  like to know how many are present in `df2`:

```
temp_ilot=df2.loc[df2['quartier']=='quartier1', 'Titre_test']
```

The output of `df2` is:

```
4665                                                  NaN
4666                                                  NaN
4667                                                  NaN
4668                                                  NaN
4669    T/61701/01/,T/61703/01/,T/61700/01/,T/61706/01...
                              ...                        
4800                                                  NaN
4804                                                  NaN
4888                                                  NaN
4890                                                  NaN
```

Any idea would be helpful.

I tried this code but I get a false response when I am sure that the information is there.

```
temp_ilot.str.contains(Shortlist)

4665      NaN
4666      NaN
4667      NaN
4668      NaN
4669    False
        ...  
4800      NaN
4804      NaN
4888      NaN
4890      NaN
4907      NaN
Name: Titre_Appart, Length: 84, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), you're asking if the series `temp_ilot` contains that string *as is*. In your question you ask:

> and I would like to know how many are present in `df2`

## If you want to see *how many* are present

You'll need to treat each part of the string as an *individual* rather than one single string.

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("""108      T/42322/C/
    108      T/37666/C/
    108      T/31411/C/
    108    T/118487/01/
    108    T/118489/01/
    108    T/108034/01/
    108    T/108045/01/
    108    T/108047/01/
    108    T/108032/01/
    108    T/108045/01/"""),
    sep=r"\s+",
    index_col=0,
    names=["Titre"],
    header=None,
)

ser = df.Titre

df2 = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("""4665                                                  NaN
4666                                                  NaN
4667                                                  NaN
4668                                                  NaN
4669    T/61701/01/,T/61703/01/,T/61700/01/,T/61706/01...
4800                                                  NaN
4804                                                  NaN
4888                                                  NaN
4890                                                  NaN"""),
    sep=r"\s+",
    names=["Titre_test"],
    index_col=[0],
    header=None,
)

ser2 = df2.Titre_test

# drop NaN, split on comma, write to list, and convert to array
arr = np.array(ser2.dropna().str.split(",").to_list())

# check if each element is in `arr` 
# and sum to determine *how many*
ser.apply(lambda x: np.isin(x, arr)).sum()
```

```py
# an example
eg = pd.Series(["T/61701/01/", "abc", "test"])

out = eg.apply(lambda x: np.isin(x, arr))
print(out)
# print(out.sum())  # >>> 1
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

## If you want to see *if any* are present

You could re-use your code but join with a pipe instead of a comma. This allows the regex "or" operator to be used.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("""108      T/42322/C/
    108      T/37666/C/
    108      T/31411/C/
    108    T/118487/01/
    108    T/118489/01/
    108    T/108034/01/
    108    T/108045/01/
    108    T/108047/01/
    108    T/108032/01/
    108    T/108045/01/"""),
    sep=r"\s+",
    index_col=0,
    names=["Titre"],
    header=None,
)

ser = df.Titre

# use a pipe (|) instead of a comma for regex "or"
shortlist = "|".join(ser)

df2 = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("""4665                                                  NaN
4666                                                  NaN
4667                                                  NaN
4668                                                  NaN
4669    T/61701/01/,T/61703/01/,T/61700/01/,T/61706/01...
4800                                                  NaN
4804                                                  NaN
4888                                                  NaN
4890                                                  NaN"""),
    sep=r"\s+",
    names=["Titre_test"],
    index_col=[0],
    header=None,
)

ser2 = df2.Titre_test

# regex is True by default
ser2.str.contains(shortlist, regex=True)
```

```py
# as an example...
out = ser2.str.contains(
    "T/61701/01/|abc|test",
    regex=True
)
print(out)
```

```
4665     NaN
4666     NaN
4667     NaN
4668     NaN
4669    True
4800     NaN
4804     NaN
4888     NaN
4890     NaN
Name: Titre_test, dtype: object
```